# Accessing html controls within an #include html file, from server side c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Following code is an example, I just want to know if this can be done.

I have an test.aspx file with this server side include tag;

```
<!--#include file="listOfCountries.htm" -->
```

Within listOfCountries.htm, I have:

```
<html>
<div>
<select id="countryList" runat="server">
<option></option>
...
</select>
</div>
</html>
```

Now, Is there a way to access "countryList" in test.aspx.cs file ?

On another note, say I didn't have the #include "Countries.htm" in test.aspx, is it possible to access the controls within Countries.htm from test.aspx.cs ? (i.e. accessing an external html file controls in cs)

Comment: The solution is to not use server-side includes (`#include`). Nobody else does. Use user-controls instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, what you're asking for isn't possible as the include file isn't actually parsed as asp.net.

What you want to do is create a "User Control" by right clicking on your project, choosing "Add new Item" and choosing "Web User Control" from the window that appears.

Within your user control you can define the markup for "countries.htm", and then expose the contents of the <select> to your C# code.

Comment: Thank you, you have to lead me to learning about Web User Controls, seems to solve my issue.. appreciate ur help...
Any websites with more info - or is look up on msdn the best option for deeper info?